# I am new to programming and I cannot figure out why my external js file wont work

Tags: javascript

I cant get my external file to work. I just want a simple alert, it works in my main html file but not when I link the external js file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Javascript Tutorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Let's Learn Javascript!</h1>
      <p class="lead">...cause Javascript Rocks.</p>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share us the folder structure and also the content of `scripts/main.js`? Also, can you check your console for any errors? AFAIK, there seems to be no errors in the content you have posted. Should be with the JS file. Please show it as well.

Comment: @PraveenKumar my js file is only `alert();`.

Comment: Sure, any errors in the console and what about the file structure?

Comment: My folder consists of two files, the html and the js.

Comment: The console says this " Unexpected token <" @PraveenKumar

Comment: In that case, you should have only `main.js`. Try that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is proper practice to define script tags in the `<head>` or `<footer>` tag. Also when linking to your Javascript file the methods in the file won't be called automatically unless you use `document.ready`.

If you wish for a function to be called as soon as the page loads use `document.ready` or create a script tag in the `<head>` or `<footer>` and call the function from there:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    myfunction();
</script>
```

Also in the JS file code shouldn't just be laying about, they should be organized/enclosed in functions.